# Wrapping a Qt library to use in C#

Tags: c#, c++, qt, wrapper, signals-slots

I have an network engine library which written in Qt and I wanted to use it in C# application, so I wrapped it with C++/CLI and statically linked together. After adding the wrapper dll to my C# application "BadImageFormatException" error occures at run time, at the dll load phase. I tried to copy all exe and dlls next to Qt dlls but nothing changed.

Also, I couldn't give reference from CLI wrapper project(DLL) to c# application directly, I added by "Browse" tab instead of "Projects" tab in VS2010. Is it just ok or is there any other way to add reference?
Thanks.

EDIT:

When I changed the C# app -> Properties -> Build -> Platform Target to x86 problem solved.

Also I created a new "Class Library"(CLR) project with wizard and redefined all qt custom build steps, now I can add project reference directly.

EDIT 2:

Now there is a serious problem, signals with custom meta-types(which are decraled as Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomTypeClass) in the native lib and working in the native apps) don't connect or cannot handled.

EDIT 3:

Looks like the problem unrelated with custom meta-types. QTcpSocket never emit the "readyRead" signal like the "connected" or others. I tried to call QCoreApplication::processEvents(); externally and nothing changed. Really weird.

---

This is how I connect native signals to slots of my proxy class:

```
...
    rawPtr = new NetworkClient(Marshaller::StringToQString(_serverIp), _serverPort); // Native
    mEventProxy = new NetworkClientEventProxy(this); // Native but mixed with gcroot<>
    QObject::connect(rawPtr, SIGNAL(signal_connected()), mEventProxy, SLOT(slot_connected()));
    QObject::connect(rawPtr, SIGNAL(signal_disconnected()), mEventProxy, SLOT(slot_disconnected()));
    QObject::connect(rawPtr, SIGNAL(signal_packetReceived(NetworkPacket)), mEventProxy, SLOT(slot_packetReceived(NetworkPacket)));
    QObject::connect(rawPtr, SIGNAL(signal_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), mEventProxy, SLOT(slot_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
...
```

And the proxy class is below:

```
#ifndef NETWORKCLIENTEVENTPROXY_H
#define NETWORKCLIENTEVENTPROXY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <vcclr.h>
#include "NetworkingCLIGlobals.h"

namespace Networking
{
    class NetworkClientEventProxy : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        NetworkClientEventProxy(NetworkClientCLI^ _clientCLI);
        ~NetworkClientEventProxy();

    public slots:
        void slot_connected();
        void slot_disconnected();
        void slot_packetReceived(NetworkPacket _packet);
        void slot_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError _socketError);

    private:
        gcroot<NetworkClientCLI^> mCLIRoot;
    };
}
#endif // NETWORKCLIENTEVENTPROXY_H
```

.cpp

```
#include "NetworkClientEventProxy.h"
#include "NetworkPacketCLI.h"
#include "NetworkClientCLI.h"

using namespace Networking;

NetworkClientEventProxy::NetworkClientEventProxy(NetworkClientCLI^ _clientCLI)
    : mCLIRoot(_clientCLI)
{
}

NetworkClientEventProxy::~NetworkClientEventProxy()
{
}

void NetworkClientEventProxy::slot_connected()
{
    // slot works
    mCLIRoot->onConnectedEventTrigger();
}

void NetworkClientEventProxy::slot_disconnected()
{
    // slot works
    mCLIRoot->onDisconnectedEventTrigger();
}

void NetworkClientEventProxy::slot_packetReceived(NetworkPacket _packet)
{
    // SLOT DOES NOT WORK !
    NetworkPacketCLI^ packet = gcnew NetworkPacketCLI();
    packet->rawPtr = &_packet;
    mCLIRoot->onPacketReceivedEventTrigger(packet);
}

void NetworkClientEventProxy::slot_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError _socketError)
{
    // slot works
    mCLIRoot->onErrorEventTrigger((SocketErrorCLI)_socketError);
}
```

Comment: Your using a 32 bit .dll in a 64 bit app or vise-versa.

Comment: I tried different configurations already, I think there are some problems with qt dlls.

Comment: Consider writing the solution as an answer if you think it's valuable to others with a similar problem.

Comment: @grek40 I'll do if I can run it. New problem described on the edited question.